# How do I delete a local branch and go back to master?

Tags: git

I created a new branch using `git checkout -b new_branch_name`.

I haven't run `git add` or `git commit` yet.
I want to get rid of this branch completely, including any new files, and switch back to master. How do I do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I delete a Git branch both locally and remotely?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2003505/how-do-i-delete-a-git-branch-both-locally-and-remotely)

Answer (score 9):

Use the following to switch back to master:

```
git checkout master
```

Use the following to delete the branch you created:

```
git branch -D new_branch_name
```

Comment: This deleted the branch, but not the files on my machine. I even went back to the master branch and pulled from github and that didnt work. I had to manually delete the files I made.

Comment: @josh There is nothing unexpected about that.  Since you did not make a commit, Git has/had no knowledge of those files.  It is wrong to expect them to be deleted when you checkout another branch; 'master' for example.

Answer (score 2):

A branch is just a pointer to a commit:

```
$ cat .git/refs/heads/master
6eef8fb523469b12abc530cd105c7b92a4a0a76a
```

So, when you delete a branch with `git branch -D branch_name`, it just deletes the file `branch_name` in `.git/refs/heads`, it doesn't touch the working tree (i.e. the actual c or java or python or whatever files you're using git to track).

To clean up any untracked files after deleting your branch, just use:

```
git clean -df
```

The `-d` flag will also remove untracked directories. The `-f` flag forces the clean in case the config option `clean.requireForce` is set to true. You can add the `-i` flag if you want to review the work interactively.

If you have any tracked files with changes after deleting your branch, you can reset those with:

```
git reset --hard
```